# Excel importing date inconsistently from Csv

Tags: php, excel, csv

I have a `.csv` file delimited with `;` (semicolon) generated from PHP code. It has three columns that contain date in `d m y` format(eg. 23 Apr 2013).

But when imported it in Excel,these date value become inconsistent.

It shows two different formats:

```
12 Oct 2006
15. Feb 06
```

In the `.CSV`, the format is same as that of 12 Oct 2006.

I have tried making them consistent by selecting the whole column and changing a single format. But it doesn't work.

Comment: what is language of your excel.. ( it's not English ?)

Comment: it is English ..

Comment: If you open the CSV file in **Notepad**, is the month a three letter abbreviation, as you show?  Or is it a number (**1-12**)?  If the latter, you need to actually import the csv file so that the text import wizard will open **before** the data gets written to an Excel cell.  If the former, I would need to see a copy of the file.

Comment: Also, if it is the case that your data is being imported into Excel into three **separate** columns, then you will need to concatenate the columns in Excel so that the dates can be recognized as such.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of different language of your Excel.

for example:

In deutsche

```
 23 Oct 2017
```

In English

```
 23 Okt 2017
```

So it will not understand `Oct` if you are using deutsche language with your excel.

same for English language it will not understand `Okt`.

For Example Deutsche

```
1. Jan 07
1. Feb 07
1. Mrz 07
1. Apr 07
1. Mai 07
1. Jun 07
1. Jul 07
1. Aug 07
1. Sep 06
1. Okt 06
1. Nov 06
1. Dez 06
```

For Example English

```
1. Jan 07
1. Feb 07
1. Mar 07
1. Apr 07
1. May 07
1. Jun 07
1. Jul 07
1. Aug 07
1. Sep 06
1. Oct 06
1. Nov 06
1. Dec 06
```